# Submodules vs components library

Tags: angular, scope, components

Hi i am in the process of learning angular and i am using a third part library for components, in this case angular material.

OK no problem i was able to use the library first example with success and now i am starting to learn an try modules and components inside modules so i created a new module on app.

in this module i created a simple hello component and tried to use the angular components library and no lucky, none of the components is loaded and i got 'xxxx-component(mat-slide-toggle) is not a known element'

then i come to stackoverflow and all besides that was to verify the imports/exports on the module, so i did it, imported the module on the new module identical i made previously on app.module.ts and to my surprise it does not work.

So 3 questions:

1. am i using angular wrongly?
2. generally people does not nest components and modules?
3. any waork around this to work?

i made a stackblitz with this behavior, for my surprise not to do with modules, only a nested component and i cant use the lib: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-n7gvvk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will separate my answer in the 3 sub questions you asked

> 1. Am I using angular wrongly?

You are not using Angular wrongly. You are using [standalone components](https://angular.io/guide/standalone-components) this is a bit different from normal components in several points:

- they are annotated with `@component({... standalone: true ...})`
- they do not belong to a module hence `standalone`
- because they do not belong to a module they have their own `imports:[]`
- you cannot add them to a module declarations

> 2. generally people does not nest components and modules?

I think this is personal preference. In the past you used modules but when they added standalone components these became obsolete IMO. If you decide not to use standalone components, I would recommend using a SharedModule where you bundle the angular material imports and import the `SharedModule` in other components

> 3. any work around for this to work?

You can just add `imports:[CommonModule, SharedModule],` to your `HomeComponent` or you create a shared module and import that inside your standalone component or `HomeModule` if you decide to make one.

---

[stackblitz standalone import](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kvy3xx?file=src/cev/home/home.component.ts)